# 2000 Mercury Marquis Check Engine Light Issue

Tags: cel, mercury, grand-marquis

I have a 2000 Mercury Marquis. When the temps were -20+ I went out and started the car often letting it run at 20 minute intervals. On the last day of the cold spell the check engine light stayed on. I did check the gas cap and it was fine. 4 days later it went off by itself. I didn't fill it with gas until after it went off.  ***What would cause this?***

It had come on before and we reset the computer and it stayed off for months until this happened. I only drive it maybe 4 miles a day.

Comment: When this happened the first time and you reset the computer, what was the code then? The easiest thing to figure out what the problem is and why the CEL is on is *to go get the codes read*. Even with the CEL off, the code is most likely stored in the computer. Without the code, there are about 2000 things which could set the CEL to being lit.

Comment: it may be a misfiring engine. engine problems are serious and i would recommend taking the car to a repair shop asap